# Одна модель для разных форм и валидаций в Yii2

Tags: yii2

Столкнулся с проблемой при использовании модели с таблицей пользователей и паролей для разных форм: авторизации и добавления новых юзеров. Получается что нужны разные правила валидации поля пароль и некоторых других полей форм, а правила задаются только в одном месте(в методе rules()). Как решить данную проблему ?

Comment: использовать разные правила валидации для разных сценариев наверное ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае подойдут [сценарии](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios) для правил валидации.
Опешите правила с указанием сценария (ключ 'on'=>'название сценария'):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // username, email and password are all required in "register" scenario
        [['username', 'email', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER],

        // username and password are required in "login" scenario
        [['username', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_LOGIN],
    ];
}
```

При создании модели, укажите сценарий:

```
$model = new User(['scenario' => User::SCENARIO_LOGIN]);
```

Или позднее:

```
$model->scenario = User::SCENARIO_LOGIN;
```